# create a tree with the ttk.Treeview widget, based on a list

Tags: python, tkinter, tree, treeview, ttkwidgets

```
["c:","c:/folder","c:/folder2","c:/folder/file.txt","c:/folder/folder3","c:/folder/folder3/file2.txt","c:/folder2/file3.txt"]
```

I want with this example that my tree seems like this:

> ```
>     c:
>     |folder
>     ||file.txt
>     ||folder3
>     |||file2.txt
>     |folder2
>     ||file3.txt
> ```

I have tried for loops but it doesnt work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def finder(sys):
    def tree_with_sys(parent: tk.Tk, system: list):
        tree = ttk.Treeview(parent)

        #Place where I don't know what to do

        return tree
    win_finder = tk.Tk()
    win_finder.geometry("1800x1000+0+0")
    win_finder.title("Finder")
    tree = tree_with_sys(win_finder, sys)
    tree.pack()
    win_finder.mainloop()
```

I think that recursives functions may help... maybe ?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved your problem. I have never used `tkinter` myself but your problem seems simple enough so I decided to give it a try and solve it.

It is simple. First of all, you don't need to create `win_finder`, `tree` is its own window, you are creating two windows here. And the window is too big for what you used as examples. I removed that part without affecting the functionality.

Now your code gives me a great starting point, `tree = ttk.Treeview(tk.Tk()); tree.pack(); tree.main_loop()` are what is needed to get the code running.

Now how to add the nodes? I just created a new file in Visual Studio Code, and inspected the attributes of `tree`, we need to use `insert` method of `Treeview` class instances here.

`insert` takes many arguments, the ones that are relevant here are positional arguments `parent` and `index`, and optional argument `text`. `text` is what is displayed, `''` as `parent` creates are top level node, else the new node is inserted to the specified parent, and `index` is where the node should be inserted to, `'end'` means the node is appended to the end.

To get what you want, we first need to split the file names by `'/'` to get the leaves, and we can then loop through each first n levels to check if the corresponding node has been created, we keep track of the nodes in a `dict` and create the new node if needed by retrieving the identifier of the parent node and add new node using the `insert` method.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

tree = ttk.Treeview(tk.Tk())

names = [
    "c:",
    "c:/folder",
    "c:/folder2",
    "c:/folder/file.txt",
    "c:/folder/folder3",
    "c:/folder/folder3/file2.txt",
    "c:/folder2/file3.txt",
]

nodes = {}

for name in names:
    leaves = name.split("/")
    parent = leaves[0]
    if (parent,) not in nodes:
        nodes[(parent,)] = tree.insert("", "end", text=parent)

    for i in range(1, len(leaves)):
        if tuple(leaves[: i + 1]) not in nodes:
            nodes[tuple(leaves[: i + 1])] = tree.insert(
                nodes.get(tuple(leaves[:i])), "end", text=leaves[i]
            )

tree.pack()
tree.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is to create a *dictionary tree* from the list and then go through the dictionary tree to insert the items into the treeview using recursion:

```py
def tree_with_sys(parent: tk.Tk, system: list):
    tree = ttk.Treeview(parent, show="tree")

    # create a dictionary tree
    dict_tree = {}
    for item in system:
        # split the path into parts
        tokens = item.split("/")
        # always start from root of tree for each path
        parent = dict_tree
        for part in tokens:
            if part not in parent:
                # create child dict
                parent[part] = {}
            # update parent
            parent = parent[part]

    # insert the items in dictionary tree into treeview using recursion
    def create_tree(parent, items):
        for item in items:
            next_parent = tree.insert(parent, "end", text=item, open=True)
            create_tree(next_parent, items[item])

    create_tree("", dict_tree)

    return tree
```

Result:

[image]